# How to make touch events through accessibilty service overlay?

Tags: android, service, touch, overlay

I am currently working on an accessibility service, which has two views. A button and a simple colored view. The colored view appears/disappears when i touch the button. 
This is the code for the service -

```
package com.hardik.accessibiltyservicetest;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.FingerprintGestureController;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import in.championswimmer.sfg.lib.SimpleFingerGestures;

public class Service extends AccessibilityService {

    FrameLayout mLayout;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    WindowManager wm;

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        // Create an overlay and display the action bar
        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY;
        lp.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        lp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, mLayout);
        wm.addView(mLayout, lp);
        configurePowerButton();

    }

    boolean is = true;

    private void configurePowerButton() {
        SimpleFingerGestures obj = new SimpleFingerGestures();
        obj.setDebug(true);
        obj.setConsumeTouchEvents(true);
        obj.setOnFingerGestureListener(new SimpleFingerGestures.OnFingerGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSwipeUp(int i, long l, double v) {
                Log.e("Swipe", "Up "+i);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSwipeDown(int i, long l, double v) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSwipeLeft(int i, long l, double v) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSwipeRight(int i, long l, double v) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPinch(int i, long l, double v) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onUnpinch(int i, long l, double v) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(int i) {
                return false;
            }
        });


        Button powerButton = mLayout.findViewById(R.id.power);
        final View img = mLayout.findViewById(R.id.view);
        powerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (is){
                    is = false;
                    img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else{
                    is =true;
                    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });

        img.setOnTouchListener(obj);


    }


}
```

and this is the layout file -

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/power"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="#80FFFFFF"
        android:text="Test"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the touch event and all works fine. but the problem is that with the current windowmanager parameter length and breadth set to match parent, the overlay blocks touch events to android ui itself, in other words no part of the android ui will respond unless the overlay is stopped, since the overlay consumes all the touch input. And the biggest setback is that i want the overlay to be just like i designed in the layout, and by setting any other length and breadth parameter the background touch problem starts, that is it once again starts consuming the touch events.

It isn't consuming all the touch events when i set the parameters to wrap content, but that doesn't give me the required ui of the service.

Also don't mind the use of gesture library, the code is a part of my personal project.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i found a fix. just make separate layouts for each element